# Can I safely emulate callback-like behaviour in Task.Run by calling the desired target procedure from TThread.Synchronize?

Tags: ios, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

I am successfully using Delphi's TRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync to query a REST API and parse the results without blocking the main thread.

This is for a mobile app with devices moving in and out of coverage, so I want to check that the server is reachable immediately prior to making the call. I tried using TRESTClient's timeout, but it takes 30 seconds to fire, even when Airplane mode is turned on.

I have a very quick and reliable function CheckServerIsAvailable, but it is synchronous. To avoid blocking the main thread, I call CheckServerIsAvailable via Task.Run, and using TThread.Synchronize to update my UI when it's done. This seems to work reliably.

However, I want the application to continue from that point and either show a message that the server is unavailable OR continue into making the call to the server. I don't want to put all the additional error checking and JSON parsing etc code inside the Thread.Synchronize procedure declaration as it will quickly become unreadable.

Thread.Synchronize docs says the anonymous procedure is called on the main thread, so I tried to continue the execution by calling another procedure from there as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
StartWithPart1;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartWithPart1;
begin
Label1.Text := 'Looking...';
AniIndicator1.Enabled := true;
TTask.Run(
  procedure
  begin
  Connected := CheckServerIsReachable;  // this is a blocking call
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    begin
    Label1.Text := ifthen(Connected, 'Connected', 'Not connected');
    AniIndicator1.Enabled := false;
    ShowMessage('leaving part 1');
    ContinueWithPart2;
    end);
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.ContinueWithPart2;
begin
ShowMessage('entering part 2');
// this is where I want to make the REST call, handle errors and parse results etc
end;
```

This seems to work correctly, with the TAniIndicator animating and labels updating correctly, but when I run the code above, the message "entering part 2" appears **before** "leaving part 1", which makes me think that my (limited) understanding of TThread.Synchronize is either incorrect or incomplete or both.

Is this approach reasonable? Why does the second message appear before the first if TThread.Synchronize is executing on the main thread? Is there a better model to be using to achieve what I'm trying to do?

UPDATE:

Thanks for the awesome help, everyone - I wasn't aware that dialogs on mobile are async and order of presentation is independent of order of creation.

For completeness, I tried an alternative approach based on subclassing TThread which seems to work equally well, and I feel results in more readable code as follows:

```
unit ServerCheck;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes,
  System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Threading,
  IdTCPClient;

type
  TServerCheck = class(TThread)
    Connected: Boolean;
    TCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
  private
    function IsServerReachable: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(host: string; port: Integer; timeout: Integer;
      callback: TNotifyEvent);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

const
  BUSY = 1;
  NOT_BUSY = 0;

constructor TServerCheck.Create(host: string; port: Integer; timeout: Integer;
  callback: TNotifyEvent);
begin
inherited Create(true);
FreeOnTerminate := true;
OnTerminate := callback;
TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create;
TCPClient.host := host;
TCPClient.port := port;
TCPClient.ReadTimeout := timeout;
TCPClient.ConnectTimeout := timeout;
end;

destructor TServerCheck.Destroy;
begin
TCPClient.Free;
inherited;
end;

function TServerCheck.IsServerReachable: Boolean;
begin
try
  if TCPClient.Tag = NOT_BUSY then
    begin
    TCPClient.Tag := BUSY;
    TCPClient.Connect;
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
    TCPClient.Tag := NOT_BUSY;
    result := true;
    end
  else
    begin
    result := false;
    end
except
  begin
  TCPClient.Tag := NOT_BUSY;
  result := false;
  end;
end;
end;

procedure TServerCheck.Execute;
begin
Connected := IsServerReachable;
end;

end.
```

and then from another form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  netCheck: TServerCheck;
begin
Label1.Text := 'Checking';
AniIndicator1.Visible := true;
AniIndicator1.Enabled := true;
netCheck := TServerCheck.Create('www.stackoverflow.com', 443, 6000, Callback);
netCheck.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Callback(Sender: TObject);
begin
AniIndicator1.Enabled := false;
AniIndicator1.Visible := false;
Label1.Text := IfThen(TServerCheck(Sender).Connected, 'Connected', 'Not connected');
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging. If you put a breakpoint at first show message and second one, which one is executed first? Android and iOS have asynchronous dialogs. that means When you run first ShowMessage, ContinueWithPart2 will immediately run, without waiting for the user input. Because of that order of showing messages might not be the one you expect. This behavior has nothing to do with TThread.Synchronize.

Comment: As @DalijaPrasnikar point out, mobile `ShowMessage` is asynchronous. Try using other means of illustrating the program flow. For testing, just use a `TMemo` for example. And include a time stamp into the visual output as well.

Comment: Yea, your code works well. As @DalijaPrasnikar wrote - in firemonkey, unlike of VCL, function `ShowMessage` does not block UI or code execution, so your code say API to start showing first message and go forward, then say APi to show second message. Result of showing messages it's threads raicing, so you can see messegges in different order.

Comment: "*I want to check that the server is reachable immediately prior to making the call*" - that is a waste of time and effort, since the actual request will have to do the same thing anyway. So just make the request normally and handle any error it may report. "*I tried using TRESTClient's timeout, but it takes 30 seconds to fire, even when Airplane mode is turned on*" - I would consider that a bug that should be reported to Embarcadero.

Comment: Thanks all, I appreciate your help immensely! 

@DalijaPrasnikar, I tried debugging in Windows, but it did not exhibit the behaviour on the device (for the reason you mention no doubt!) I am struggling to get debugging on my device working reliably.

Comment: @dalija-prasnikar if you could post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark my question answered.